# How to use Android Studio's minSdkVersion properly

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

See the screenshot below I have of my Android Studio project setup:

[image]

What I see here is that I am compiling with the android-L SDK version, with target SDK version of 19 and minimum SDK version of 19.

I tried to run this app (which is simply the template blank activity app with no changes) on a Samsung S4 v4.4.2 phone, and the IDE tells me that it is not compatible.

Obviously I'm not understanding what the three `{compile,min,target}SdkVersion` definitions are. Could someone please enlighten me?

Comment: Did you try compiling with the version 19 compiler? It seems a little weird to be compiling to a higher API level than the target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apps compiled with the Android L preview SDK can currently only be installed on devices running the Android L preview.

Until the Android L preview is released, I wouldn't recommend compiling with it (or using any piece of it) unless you are specifically interesting in testing out Android L functionality or APIs. If this is the case, create an emulator with the preview image or get a device that supports the preview images that Google has released and install the preview there.

Addressing the three version properties:

- **compileSdkVersion** is the version of the Android SDK that your application is compiled with. It should typically be the latest stable release of Android, and will not affect how your app is filtered in the Play Store (L preview excluded). Using the latest version simply makes newer APIs available to your application should you choose to use them for your users running newer versions of Android.
- **minSdkVersion** is the minimum version of Android your application requires to run on a user's device (or that you support). If a user is running an older version than this, they cannot see your app in the Play Store and will not be able to install the APK manually either.
- **targetSdkVersion** is the latest version that you explicitly support and have tested with. The framework uses this to disable certain compatibility features for newer versions. For example, if your targetSdkVersion is between 8 and 14, you will not get the Holo theme. If it is above 14, your application will default to Holo.